# Interrupting loop in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a loop that runs but would like it to stop on the press of a button and start again when another is pressed. This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private loopon As Boolean
Public Function ping(ByVal server As String) As String
    Dim s As New Stopwatch
    s.Start()
    My.Computer.Network.Ping(server)
    s.Stop()
    Return s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loopon = True
    TextBox1.Text = "Ping results:"
    Do While loopon = True
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
        TextBox1.AppendText(ping("server name here"))
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    loopon = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    TextBox1.Text = "Ping results:"
    loopon = True
End Sub
End Class
```

When I try to run the code, with debugging, my computer gives me a blue screen after a while and restarts. I'm pretty sure I messed up with the exiting of the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: No remotely sane VB code is capable of giving a blue screen of death on a clean system. Check your drivers.

Comment: Also, don't block the UI thread.

Comment: What you have is an infinite loop when the form loads.  You're going to want to take a look at threading.

Comment: As SLaks mentioned, your best bet is to rewrite this to use a new thread that does the ping loop. That thread can call back to the main thread to find the status of your `loopon` variable. And within the same button click that sets it to false, you can alternatively, if it is false already, set it to true and start the ping thread back up.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend continuously pinging a server (and the owner of the server probably won't be pleased). Instead, I would start a Timer and ping the server on each Timer Tick.  Stop the timer when the `loopon` variable is set to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Timer to ping (say) every 5 seconds until the "Stop" button is clicked. In the Form Designer, drag a Timer onto the form, and use this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private stopPing As Boolean

    Public Sub Ping(ByVal server As String)
        Dim s As New Stopwatch
        s.Start()
        My.Computer.Network.Ping(server)
        s.Stop()
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = "Ping results:"
        Ping "server name here"
        Timer1.Interval = 5000 'Set timer Interval to 5 seconds
        Timer1.Start
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        stopPing = True
    End Sub

    Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If stopPing Then Timer1.Stop Else Ping "server name here"
    End Sub
End Class
```